# Without Trial and Error or a dental professional, how can you determine your size of Interdental Brush?

Tags: dentistry

How can you determine by himself  which size of  [TePe Interdental Brushes](http://tepecanada.com/consumers_en/tepe-interdental-brushes-original/) fits (your [Interproximal Space](http://www.dentaid.com/en/interproximal-cleaning))?

Disregard and pretermit:

1. Trial and Error (ie: randomly selecting a size, and then purchasing a pack of these brushes)
2. or seeing the dental professional (e.g. dentist, oral hygienist) for him/her to determine the size (to avert costs).

Answer (score 1):

Some companies offer a probe that allows you to measure on your own the spaces between the teeth. Here is an example
[image: Curaprox Interdental Access Probing]